# Math in Dart - working with numbers other than base 10

Tags: dart

I was trying to do some math in something other than base 10, and wanted to get some input from the Dart community on possible directions I can take.

So, for example, suppose p = 2. Then, looking at 100 in base 2:

```
100 = (1 · 26
) + (1 · 25
) + (0 · 24
) + (0 · 23
) + (1 · 22
) + (0 · 21
) + (0 · 20
)
```

so

```
100 base 2 = 1100100
```

Add 1 to each digit and multiply the answers together:

```
(1 + 1)(1 + 1)(0 + 1)(0 + 1)(1 + 1)(0 + 1)(0 + 1) = 8
```

Try it for 3:

```
100 = (1 · 34
) + (0 · 33
) + (2 · 32
) + (0 · 31
) + (1 · 30
)
```

so

```
100 base 3 = 10201

(1 + 1)(0 + 1)(2 + 1)(0 + 1)(1 + 1) = 12
```

In Dart, I came up with the following;

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11345381

```dart
int rows = 1000000000;
      int total = 0;
      for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++ ){
        total += i.toRadixString(7)
            .split('')
            .map((s) => int.parse(s) + 1)
            .reduce((prev,next) => prev*next);
      }
print('${total} results');
```

This does work, and seems to be ok for small number of rows. But for larger numbers, it is really quite slow.

As shown, I am converting an int to a string (resulting in a string representation of a number), splitting it, mapping the split characters back to ints, adding 1 to each int, and then multiplying them all together.

Am I missing something when it comes to working with numbers in Dart, other than base 10?

Comment: I still don't get want you actually want to do. Do you just want to convert numbers between different radixes?

Comment: As in the 2 examples above, I am getting the value of 100 by converting it to base X. Then, with the converted value, adding 1 to each digit and multiplying the sums together. It seems to be inefficient to convert to String and then back again. But I am not sure how else I could do this in Dart. My main motivation is that the time it takes to calculate this using large numbers is too slow.

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question :( What do you want to achieve?

Converting numbers to other bases can be done like this:

    print((100).toRadixString(2));
    print((100).toRadixString(3));

1100100
10201

Comment: do you simply want to display a number in radix P and then sum up all numbers of that representation with +1? Then I don't see another way.

I am asking because I want to understand the mathematical background behind it why you need it.

Comment: Try changing `.split('').map(...)` to `.codeUnits.map((x)=>x-47)` and see how big a difference it makes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through the string seems inefficient. How about doing it directly?

```dart
int digitProduct(int n, int base) {  // non-negative n and base only
  int product = 1;
  while (n > 0) {
    int digit = n % base;
    n = n ~/ base;
    product *= (digit + 1);
  }
  return product;
}
main() {
  int rows = 1000000000;
  int total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    total += digitProduct(i, 7);
  }
  print("${total} results");
}
```

Also 1000000000 is a pretty big number. If it takes a microsecond per row, it will still take ~16 minutes to complete.

Division by arbitrary bases is slow. If you hardcode the base to be 7, it'll probably be significantly faster (I expect ~90% of the time spent in digitProduct to be used on ~/ and %).

Comment: Quite a bit faster. Thanks.